# How to get Output to Display

Tags: c

I am trying to get the output to display payment and the balance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void)
{    float loan_amount, rate, payment, monthly_amount, interest;
     int t, i=1;
     printf("Enter Loan Amount");

     scanf("%i", &loan_amount);

     printf("Enter Interest rate:");
     scanf("%f", &rate);
     printf("Enter Monthly Payment:");
     scanf("%f", &payment);
     printf("Enter number of payments:");
     scanf("%d",&t);
     while(loan_amount>0;
     {
          interest = loan_amount*rate/12;
          monthly_amount = (loan_amount+interest - payment);
          if(monthly_amount>0)
               printf("Balance remaing after %d payment: $ %.2f\n",i, monthly_amount);
          loan_amount = monthly_amount;
          i++;
     }
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: ...And what is happening? What are your inputs and outputs? What do you expect?

Comment: Is this your real code? `while(loan_amount>0;` is a syntax error.

Comment: while(loan_amount>0; => while(loan_amount>0)

Comment: My inputs is the data I enter for Interest Rate , Monthly Payment, Loan Amount, Number of payments per Month.

Comment: suggest not placing statements after the opening brace '}' on the same line as that formatting style only makes the code harder to read/understand by humans

Comment: For several reasons, the posted code does not compile.  Please enable all warnings and recompile, then fix the warnings (and the errors) output by the compiler, then re-post the code

Answer (score 1):

I found few mistakes in code, here I am not mentioning about Logic you used ,just coding mistakes.

1. *scanf("%i", &loan_amount)*, here *%i* should change to *%f* because loan_amount is float.
2. *while(loan_amount>0;* is syntax error it should be *while(loan_amount>0){*
3. Please change *interest = loan_amount*rate/12;* to *interest = loan_amount*rate/12.0;* , some compilers will truncate the floating result to integer when an integer value is used for division.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I commented the lines I changed

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void)
{    
 float loan_amount, rate, payment, monthly_amount, interest;
 int t, i=1;
 printf("Enter Loan Amount");

 scanf("%f", &loan_amount); // changed %i to %f since loan_amount is a float

 printf("Enter Interest rate:");
 scanf("%f", &rate);
 printf("Enter Monthly Payment:");
 scanf("%f", &payment);
 printf("Enter number of payments:");
 scanf("%d",&t);
 while(loan_amount>0) //Changed ; to )
 {
      interest = loan_amount*rate/12;
      monthly_amount = (loan_amount+interest - payment);
      if(monthly_amount>0)
           printf("Balance remaing after %d payment: $ %.2f\n",i, monthly_amount);
      loan_amount = monthly_amount;
      i++;
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Should `rate` be divided by `100` to yield a proper result.